# Multiple bindings as parameter for converter WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I am trying to change the fill brush of an ellipse. It didn't work, so as a quick fix i did some manual labor:

```
<Ellipse Height="55" Width="55" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="DarkGray" 
Visibility="{Binding Model.TransitLow, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<Ellipse Height="55" Width="55" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="White" 
Visibility="{Binding Model.IndicationHigh, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<Ellipse Height="55" Width="55" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="DarkGray" 
Visibility="{Binding Model.IndicationLow, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<Ellipse Height="55" Width="55" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="White" 
Visibility="{Binding Model.High, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<Ellipse Height="55" Width="55" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="DarkGray" 
Visibility="{Binding Model.Low, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<Ellipse Height="55" Width="55" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="Red" 
Visibility="{Binding Model.FeedbackError, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<Ellipse Height="55" Width="55" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="Red" 
Visibility="{Binding Model.FunctionFailed, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<Ellipse Height="55" Width="55" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="Red" 
Visibility="{Binding Model.LossOfXE, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

As you can see i have basically just created layers, and used hide and show algorithm.

Ideally all these binding attributes would go into one converter doing the logic and returning one brush for one ellipse.

Ideally something like this is what i want:

```
<Ellipse Height="55" Width="55" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="{Binding Model.LossOfXE,Model.FunctionFailed....... Converter={StaticResource attrsToBrushConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: My knowledge of WPF is not really profound but I think what you are looking for is a MulitValueConverter

Comment: What do you mean by `fill brush of an ellipse`?

Comment: I think idealy you dont want to have the layers and yo also do not want to sent the ellipse a list of available colors. You would likely want some other sort of control to tell the code behind to change and update the ellipse

Comment: I don't have code behind, that is the point. I mean by fill brush, the brush to use to fill the ellipse.

Comment: You kinda should though. mrsargent has a good clue for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the color of the ellipse changes from multiple conditions you can use the `IMultiValueConverter` interface.  For example you have 2 buttons that will determine what color the `ellipse` is.  So you can code your converter to look something like this

```
public class EllipseColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool btn1 = (bool)values[0];
        bool btn2 = (bool)values[1];

        if (btn1 && !btn2)
            return Brushes.Red;
        else if (btn2 && !btn1)
            return Brushes.Blue;
        else if (btn1 && btn2)
            return Brushes.Pink;
        else
            return Brushes.Black;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then in your `xaml` you can implement

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <local:EllipseColorConverter x:Key="ellipseColorConvert"/>
</Window.Resources>

 <Ellipse Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Height="100">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ellipseColorConvert}">
                <Binding ElementName="btn1" Path="IsPressed"/>
                <Binding ElementName="btn2" Path="IsPressed"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="button 1" x:Name="btn1"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="button 2" x:Name="btn2"/>
```